# How to work around Unity not displaying interfaces in the Inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If have an `interface`, say...

```
public interface ITool
{
    void Use();
}
```

and I have a `MonoBehaviour` class that implements the interface, say...

```
public class Equipment : MonoBehaviour, ITool
{
    ...

    public void Use()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and I want to reference the interface in another `MonoBehaviour` class, say...

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ITool tool;
    ...

    void Update()
    {
        ...
        tool.Use();
        ...
    }
}
```

then I find that the inspector in Unity, looking at `Player` doesn't show `tool` and so I cannot drag a reference from some object that has an `ITool` component.

From searching, I can see people saying that interfaces aren't supported in the Unity inspector and that people have found ways of avoiding interfaces.

What ways?

Without creating a custom wrapper class for each interface, [such as this one](https://forum.unity.com/threads/released-iunified-c-interfaces-for-unity.206988/), how can I retain the benefits of interface classes *and* keep my scripts decoupled? (i.e. I don't want to have to put `public Equipment tool` in `Player` as `Player` shouldn't have to know about the `Equipment` script... and should also let me reference a different type of `ITool`.)

Comment: Why the downvote? This is an issue I've seen come up many times in forums. I want to understand how to work around it as I've encountered it myself. I've taken time to formulate a clear question that is focused and uses a minimal example. What's to downvote?

Answer (score 2):

depending on your exact use case maybe [`[SerializeReference]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeReference.html) already might solve your issue.

Beyond that unfortunately there is no easy straight forward way. A lot of people already did this via custom property drawers / Editor scripts though. A full implementation would be a bit too broad IMO.

---

However, - again depending on your actual use case - a complete alternative to interfaces might be a common base class like

```
public abstract class BaseTool : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public abstract void Use(); 
}
```

and then

```
public class Equipment : BaseTool 
{ 
    public override void Use()
    { 
        ...
    }
}
```

and finally in player use a

```
 public BaseTool tool;
```

This is basically exactly the way Unity does it with e.g. `Collider` or `Renderer` or `Texture` which are abstract base classes for many different child types.

Comment: Taking my example, putting `[SerializeReference] public ITool tool;` caused the label "Tool" to appear in the inspector but with a blank space for the value. I shall investigate custom property drawers. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can use above solution, and keep implement ITool in abstract class

**public abstract class BaseTool: MonoBehaviour, ITool**

Comment: @CongDanLuong question would then be what is the purpose of the interface `ITool` if anyway you will always go through the `BaseTool` class? ;)